# Trying to find 2 equalities

Tags: linear-algebra

**STRICTLY: I do not need coding help. I just need to know why 2 equations won't come to a single equality**

I'm trying to use a conditional statement made of 4 equations to see if it is possible to take the correct number from a parabola equation.

I understand that a parabola is very difficult to get around to find one specific number (if it's possible).

My equation that I iterate to get to the upper limit (2^32)-1 is:

$$x= 3*(x + n_y + 3)$$

Each $n_x$ is actually a number being hid inside the limit number. My understanding (misunderstanding perhaps) is I may be able to divide $$(x - j)/3 - 3$$, when
$$j=n_y$$ to get the number that is the lower X. It will work with 0, 1, & 2 as output. But that's not helpful. Here's how I check my answer:

```
while (a > 10) {
  j = 0;
  while (j < 127) {
    assrt = (a - j*3)/3 - 3;
    x = (a - 9)/3 - j;
    if (x == assrt && assrt*3 + j*3 + 9 - a == 0 && assrt%3 == 0 && 0 == a/3 - (assrt + j + 3)) {
        a = x;
        cout << a << "**" << j << " ..." << flush;
        //cout << cnt << "." << flush;
        n.val.push_back(static_cast<int>(j));
        break;
    }
    j++;
  }
}
```

When I leave the second condition out (`assrt*3 + j*3 + 9 - a`) it goes through, but not without the number `j` (which is actually `nx`) being very low. In fact it barely varies.

My question is, I have $3(x+n_y+3)=x$ each $n$ is a ASCII Table number from 0-127. If I take $3(27+10+3)=120$ I should be able to get thru $x$ and $assrt$, below, to get $x=27$ and $n_y=10$ by asking which numbers make the two variables both equal, evenly divisible by 3, and minus the $n_y$ get 27. How can I do that?

Comment: What are the two equations? It's a little hard to see what's going on there. [Useful guide to MathJax, our equation script](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: assrt*3 + j*3 + 9 - a == 0 & 0 == a/3 - (assrt + j + 3) If I only use the second  equation, I get output. But if I add the first herein, I get nothing

Comment: I can't make any sense of your question.  I suggest you start from the beginning and explain exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How's that? I made it a little clearer by using the MathJax. I know my writing can be peculiar.

Comment: As far as I can tell, those equations are identical and - from the definition of *assrt* - trivially true; you shouldn't need to test them at all. (and +1 for working to clarify your question)

Comment: If I leave them out, the equations will accept any answer that is divisible by 3. I, for instance need the $$n_y$$ exception that leads me to dividing this limited number, $$x$$ to 0 after all is divided from it. @Joffan

Comment: I wonder if the issue is the type of the variables. Are they restricted to integers?  (if you use single dollar signs `$n_y$` $\to n_y$ you get in-line equations)

Comment: Oh whoops, I'm sorry. I'm new to MathJax. Please, excuse me. Is there anything I should do to $x$ or $assrt$?

Comment: My guess is that `assrt` is being evaluated to an integer. Possibly `a/3`, in the second equation, is also.

Comment: What do you mean by "take the correct number from a parabola equation"?   What parabola equation?  Why do you think a parabola is "difficult to get around"?  What do you mean by "being hid inside the limit number"?

Comment: I agree with @RobertIsrael - there is enough odd phrasing (from a mathematical viewpoint) to suggest you are trying to do something that could be achieved more simply. You would probably make better use of the talents on this site if you ask another question that looks at a broader picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Alright. I'll edit the question than. Thank you very much for all your help so far.

Comment: @Joffan They're all unsigned int except for j.

Comment: Don't edit this question, because you already have an answer (and some discussion) - ask another one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael If I'm not mistaken the reason I'm getting a small variation instead of what I'm looking for, which is a widely varying subset, is that is starts climbing the $x$ and $n_y$ it finds numbers that to my dismay fit the equation but do not do it justice. I assumed that was a Parabolic Equation because of that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your parabola equation is, but if you are trying to extract a number from your parabola the solution is just simple:

In case your parabola takes this form: $y-3=2(x-1)^2$ simplify it then write in code

y=(2*(x-1)(x-1)) + 3

a similar code that could try to solve it looks like this

```
xsol=0
i=-100
y=5 //looking for solution

do while(xsol<2)
{
    if( y==((2*(i-1)(i-1)) + 3) ){
        xsol++
        //print value of i
    }
    i++
}
```

Here xsol stands for the number of correct x value it found out, there are two only thus it must continue solving while xsol<2. Notice that the IF statement tests a trial number $i$ if it satisfies the parabola, else it would not increment xsol since a particular value of $i$ does not meet the equality. Then finaly incrementing $i$. The new $i$ will then be tested on the next loop. Once two solutions are obtained, the loop will also stop, and you have found out your answer.

Note: In an event that your x are not exact whole number then you got to do approximations and will more likely get to use inequalities than "==".