# Seeking 2 values from a 3 value equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been searching for a compression method that can be expressed as a math formula. I decided that since $0-127$ is the range, and $3$ is a nominal prime number, that I would perhaps get some easily reverse engineered numbers back. So by taking off at $0$ (or $1$), I might get that compression utility I've been dreaming of. It works like a charm going into compressed format, but the trick is not quite working as it should to decompress.

**So I Strictly State: This is not about coding, this is about math and if there is any construct like this in mathematics. If someone knows of one, I'd like to know.**

My equation goes from 0 and starts to iteratively add and multiply from that point. They do this with initial problem being $x = 3(0 + n_0 + 3)$ Then it would take that, and iterate over it.. hence if $n_0=27$ than the answer would be $x=90$ so I would then go forth with $x = 3(90 + n_1 + 3)$ where $n_1$ is equal to the next number I wish to insert. I do this till my next data point would be over $2^{32}-1$. My question is:

Are the only answers to this going to be parabolic when I reverse engineer it with $$a = (x - 9)/3-j; j = \{ n_{y-1}, n_{y-2}, \ldots n_0 \}$$

I'm trying to use a multi-check method of 3 separate equations to find if it is the correct number from a parabola equation.

$$a == assrt$$ $$assrt*3 + j*3 + 9 - x == 0$$ $$0 == a/3 - (assrt + j + 3)$$

$assrt$ is the previous $x$ point from the initial equation, it must be divisible by 3.

$$assrt=(x−j)/3−3$$

So far, I understand that it may be parabolic which may be very difficult to get around in order to find one specific number, if possible.

Each $x$ is actually a number being hid inside a larger (of $x=3(x + n_y +3)$) number. My understanding (misunderstanding perhaps) is if I use to get the number that is the next $x$ down. However, I get one chance at this. Let's say that my $n_y$s all are between 0-127?

How do I get the right one? It seems that nearly anything will fit into the formulas I gave.

If I take away conditions I get some answers. A condition out like $(assrt*3 + j*3 + 9 - a)$, once removed, returns answers hardly close to valid. It barely varies, even when I just take the first number that works.

So, To conclude:

Is this just a parabola?
And if Not, then how do I get the answers I want?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Does $2^32-1$ mean $2^{32}-1$? What is $n_y$ and how does it depend on $x$?  You refer to "$4$ equations"...what are the four equations?

Comment: Could you use more mathematical and less programming notation. Better to describe the initial problem, from existing description it is a kind of reversal engineering to get it.

Comment: It was supposed to be $2^{32} - 1$ and $n_y$ is a typed character in machine code represented by a number. They equally depend on each other for their presence as being like a plane in the problem $x=3(x+n_y+3)$ which iterates, and upon reaching the value, is this _plane_

Comment: @z100 Yes I can, I'll strip the code out. My question is how can I always get back the real $n_y$. It seems to be a parabolic question and I can't reach the definitive answer.

Comment: @lulu The _plane_ firstly as I try to discombobulate these numbers from one another is something just below $ulim$

Comment: You didn't clarify the initial problem in 1st version of the same question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835917/trying-to-find-2-equalities , so your expectations in 2nd attempt really cannot be optimistic. Give the start position of your task, not a mess of yourself defined variables after several steps from which some were not correct. It seems you have some equation(s) and want to find a solution using one of itteration methods, is it true?

Comment: You appear to be trying to solve some equation or system of equations iteratively, but I really can't sort out what the original problem was nor the method you are trying to use.  Can you edit the question so as to clearly and precisely state what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @z100 Yes I have the original problem now.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Why? It's simply a math equation. Unless you're saying that it's an open ended question. This is simply a math question though. You'll have to point it out how I've eluded the rules. If it's because I'm nowhere near the level of the class that uses this, and I have reason to want to know (which is why I ask) then it should be possible to put this up on SE. You'll have to show where to put it than though.

Comment: No, I'm asking about math. If my point is to use it in code, that cannot be a hampering to find out the way to properly point it into my conditional statement. I don't want help with code. It's right there in bold, sir. I just need to know how to solve it. @TheGreatDuck

Comment: I see the edit, but I still have no idea what the question is. Voting to close the question.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I beleive it is a question about math. But in the real sense of the word it is a question of the real world, that applies to 3rd line customer support ... i think this discussion will finish in the chat ...

Comment: The question is, how do I solve it? Instead of being able to use any number, how do I get it the one I want? @lulu

Comment: How do you solve what?  I see no question here.  You just throw out a lot of variables with no explanation.

Comment: @z100 You understand a bit of what I'm talking about yes? Is this just a parabolic equation and there is no one answer? Or is there a way to depict the original list of numbers, in reverse. through a mathematical formula?

Comment: @lulu I don't want to disregard your intent to understand, it's just that I want one of two things from this post: A. A definitive report that this is and can only have a parabolic answer. OR B. How do I move backwards through the list?

Comment: just to explain the "3rd line customer support" -among clear description missing data, data without any sense,  incorrect data, but still some sense which enable the solution

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I don't want to seem peckish but it seems you're just lauding a lot of 'I can't do this, make it go away'. This is pure algebra. Can you recommend a tag for it? Anyone? Might get me closer to a answer.

Comment: @z100 I added more to the butt of the first paragraph. That's my real question. Here's something for clarity: Should I just erase everything BUT the first paragraph?

Comment: Try to go one more step back  -- where from you got those equatons

Comment: @z100 I hate to be the dullard but I made this equation up. It's just an algebra equation.

Comment: @z100 is it necessary for me to have a reason to solve this posted on the question? I would assume not. It's not kosher to ask questions about it on MSE.

Comment: Hi @thexiv - when I mentioned asking a second quesiton, I really hoped you would give a bit more context to the equation, because it could well be that the folks here can help you avoid iterating altogether or advise on a better approach to get your solution. It's not so much "why" you want these answer as letting everyone see a bit more than one cog in the machine.

Comment: @joffan ! Great to see you, I just totally redid the question. I want that magical formula to do it! Please reload the page and see if it's a good question now. Thanks

Comment: @thexiv The main problem here is that you jump in without any story. It's like there's a paragraph or two missing right at the start; maybe something like: **I'm trying to find numbers that fit the following criteria: - X;  - Y;  - Z. My approach has been to iterate this system of formulas - f; - g; - h**

Comment: @joffan And I will now try to put that in, Thank you Joffan

Comment: @joffan hi, I added what I think you meant. Can you try to finagle this one out for me, again?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - if I understand - to code up say $(n_0,n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4)$, you generate 
\begin{align}
x_0 &=3(0+n_0+3), \\
\text{ then }x_1 &=3(x_0+n_1+3), \\
x_2 &=3(x_1+n_2+3), \\
x_3 &=3(x_2+n_3+3), \\
\text{ and }x_4 &=3(x_3+n_4+3)
\end{align}
which is your final retained value.

Unfortunately this won't result in a unique coding. For example, $(n_0,n_1) = (32,120)$ produces the same $x_1=684$ as $(48,72)$. So unfortunately there is no way to reverse that process and get unique values back - if that is what you want.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you. I wanted verification on my resolute, ad I now it is verified I have none :)